# BackgroundWorker Suspend

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` `_worker`

```
void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Interval = 5000;
    _timer.Start();
}
```

When it gets to the line `_timer.Start()` it thinks it has finished so fires the `RunWorkerCompleted event`.

I don't want it to finish until the `_timer.Interval` time has been reached and the `_timer Elapsed event` has been trigger:

```
void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            listBox1.Invoke((Action)(() => listBox1.Items.Add("Do Things Thread")));
        else
            listBox1.Items.Add("Do Things Completed");

        _worker.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)i / (decimal)20) * 100));

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    _timer.Stop();
}
```

Because I need the `BackgroundWorker` to report back some progress.

How do I do this. I need it to run on a different `thread`.

Comment: You are aware there are already threaded timers?

Comment: I am not.... can you point me to the MSDN page?

Comment: Yeh sure - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Also, System.Timers.Timer can be threaded, as per MSDN - "If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant."

Comment: OOOOooooo how to do you make something reentrant?

Comment: Here something really wrong. The backgroundWorker.DoWork() already runs in another thread and their you are going to start a timer (which runs on another thread). I think you really misunderstood something. So what is your root task you like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to round up the discussion and the solution.

System.Timers.Timer will automatically thread the timer event for you unless you supply a sync object, as discussed in MSDN:

> If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is
>   raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event
>   lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another
>   ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be
>   reentrant.

This means that the background worker becomes superfluos. You can simply have your timer event code run as is (as it uses invoke to interact with the UI anyhow).

It does mean that these events can run concurrently if they take a long time. However, you can of course stop and start the timer in the event callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your _timer_Elapsed event is on a different thread. The instance of timer will expire as soon as the control flow passes through the _worker_DoWork function. The scope of your timer object variable is restricted to the function and hence it will not work this way.

I would suggest that you put put Thread.sleep(5000) in the timer _worker_dowork function itself. It will not affect your application as the thread will sleep and the gui will still be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I think, just by playing around with what I've done, is that I've invoked the progress bar, so I don't need the ReportProgress:

```
_worker.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)i / (decimal)20) * 100));
```

Changed to :

```
if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
    progressBar1.Invoke((Action)(() => progressBar1.Value = (int)(((decimal)i / (decimal)20) * 100)));
else
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(((decimal)i / (decimal)20) * 100);
```

That means, I don't have to suspend the BackgroundWorker, and the timer was invoked on a different thread and will remain until disposed of????

Comment: You're mixing threads though. Your timer will raise the elapsed in an event anyhow. Just do the invoke and don't bother with a background worker at all.

Comment: Will the UI responsiveness be affected? I think i'm going down the System.Threading.Timers route anyways!

Comment: No, it's threaded. UI will only be affected when you do something on that thread.

Comment: I got rid of background worker completely and it all works absolutely fine!